# Nested accept() to get files in subdirectory in one String array

Tags: java

i am trying to get the list of files in an array from a root directory and the subdirectories inside the root. Considering `C:\` to be my root directory. I also want to get the list of `C:\abc` and `C:\def` according to a specific pattern of file names. Here is the code i tried.

```
public String[] getFilesList(File path){
        String[] filesList = null;
        final String[] directories = null;
        try {
            properties.load(new StoricoPV_ISAU().getFile());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        filesList = path.list(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                if(name.matches(Constants.INTERNA_REGEX)){
                    return true;
                }else if(name.matches(Constants.SISS_REGEX)){
                    return true;
                }else if(new File(properties.getProperty(Constants.PATH_NAME)+name).isDirectory()){
                    //error here: The final local variable directories cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type
                    directories = new File(properties.getProperty(Constants.PATH_NAME)).list(new FilenameFilter() {
                        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                            if(name.matches(Constants.INTERNA_REGEX)){
                                return true;
                            }else if(name.matches(Constants.SISS_REGEX)){
                                return true;
                            }else{
                                log.info("Invalid file or directory: "+name);
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        return filesList;
    }
```

Okay, i know that the variable `directories` can not be `final` but at the same time, it needs to be `final` to work inside this method. How can i modify my logic so that eventually the list of all files in `C:\`, `C:\abc` and `C:\def` are all returned in variable `filesList` according to the file pattern i specified. Any help on this would be really appreciated.

NOTE: I dont need to get beyond level 1 depth in directory. For example, we have to ignore any directory within the direcotry `C:\abc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing in my mind is recursion. Because you only need on level folder, so I add a variable to control that in case of changing requirement.

```
public String[] getFilesList(File path) {
    int deepth = 1; // Control the deepth of recursion
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    getFilesList(path, list, deepth);
    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}

public void getFilesList(File path, final List<String> list, int deepth) {
    if (deepth >= 0) {
        final int newDeepth = deepth - 1;
        String[] subList = path.list(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            File subFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + name);
            if (subFile.isFile()) {
                if (name.matches(Constants.INTERNA_REGEX)) {
                return true;
            } else if (name.matches(Constants.SISS_REGEX)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                // log.info("Invalid file or directory: " + name);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            getFilesList(subFile, list, newDeepth);
        }
        return false;
      }
    });

    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(subList));
    }
}
```

Comment: It seemed that code format had a problem, sorry about that.

Comment: I like the answer! It pretty much solves the problem! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use something simpler like these? It will return just the filenames filtered (matching the regex and only the first level of the folder) as you seem to want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    File source = new File("C:\\Users\\mofh\\Desktop\\test");
    getFiles(fileNames, source, source);
}


public static void getFiles(List<String> fileNames, File dir, File parent) {
    try {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                if (!file.getAbsolutePath().equals(parent.getAbsolutePath()) &&
                        file.getParent().equals(parent.getAbsolutePath())) {
                    getFiles(fileNames, file, dir);
                }
            } else {
                if (file.getName().matches(Constants.INTERNA_REGEX) ||
                        file.getName().matches(Constants.SISS_REGEX)) {
                    fileNames.add(file.getCanonicalPath());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have a bottleneck, that is memory. Because i have more than 8000 files on this directory and i attempt only to get the names of the files and not the files themselves. I also want to reject the files that dont match my pattern so i can reduce the list of files i get eventually. I just wrote a longer code but it works fine now. Thank you for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i came up with. Can't get the list of files instead (by using `listFiles()` method) because i have a lot of files.

```
public String[] getFilesList(File path){
        String[] filesList = null;
        final List<String> directories = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            properties.load(new StoricoPV_ISAU().getFile());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        filesList = path.list(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                if(name.matches(Constants.INTERNA_REGEX)){
                    return true;
                }else if(name.matches(Constants.SISS_REGEX)){
                    return true;
                }else if(new File(properties.getProperty(Constants.PATH_NAME)+name).isDirectory()){
                    directories.add(properties.getProperty(Constants.PATH_NAME)+name);  
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        String[] tempList = null;
        for(String directory :directories){
            tempList = new File(directory).list(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                if(name.matches(Constants.INTERNA_REGEX)){
                    return true;
                }else if(name.matches(Constants.SISS_REGEX)){
                    return true;
                }else if(new File(properties.getProperty(Constants.PATH_NAME)+name).isDirectory()){
                    log.info("Invalid file or directory name");
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
            filesList = (String[])ArrayUtils.addAll(filesList, tempList);
        }

        return filesList;
    }
```